# How to get an Output from 'DispatchWorkflow' in Elsa Workflow?

Tags: elsa-workflows

I'm trying to get the output form a dispatched workflow at the main workflow, but the object that is returned on the source workflow returns empty. I'm attaching screenshots for reference below,

[image: Source workflow]

[image: Dispatched workflow]